# ConfigurationSaveMode in C#

Tags: c#, configuration-files, msdn

ConfigurationSaveMode defines 3 ways to save a file according to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.configuration.configurationsavemode.aspx

1) Full save: The entire configuration file is re-written

2) Modified: The properties modified by code are written to the file.

3) Minimal: Causes only properties that differ from inherited values to be written to the configuration file.

What is meant by "inherited values"? Can someone please explain the minimal mode with an example.

Answer (score 2):

All .NET applications inherit basic configuration settings and defaults from a file named Machine.config (located at systemroot\Microsoft .NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG). The Machine.config file is used for client-side/server-wide configuration settings (DB Provider, Configuration Sections, ...)

The root of the ASP.NET configuration hierarchy is a file referred to as the **root Web.config file**  (same directory as machine.config). The root Web.config file inherits all of the settings in the Machine.config file. Because each ASP.NET application inherits default configuration settings from the root Web.config file, you need to create Web.config files only for settings that override the default settings. That's why you don't need a huge config file
in each asp.net app.

So, "Causes only properties that differ from inherited values to be written to the configuration file" means that the saved configuration file will contains only what is not in root web.config/machine.config.

Of course, it'sd a bit more complicated (scope, virtual directories, ..) but the concept is here.